# Vertical center on a div not working

Tags: html, css, centering

From start i search for long time solutions and similar questions on stackoverflow, but no one works for me.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ruudy/MJe3H/

I want to center material-container verticaly, it works only horizontaly.

I tried different solutions like:

```
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
margin: auto;
```

---

```
display: -moz-box;
-moz-box-align: center;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-align: center;
display: box;
box-align: center;
```

---

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: center;
```

I try to see if a parent div make the vertical center not work but dont find any clue.

Thanks in advance.

PD: Must be a simple thing but i dont find it.

Comment: vertically align to what?? to template-container??

Comment: Quote: I want to center material-container verticaly, it works only horizontaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this site on vertical center objects, it has been very useful for me.

[vertical-centering-with-css](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)

Answer (score 1):

You can align a container vertical only when it has a known height with a CSS trick.

Set the container absolute with a top position of 50% and then add a negative margin of the half size from the container.

```css
.parent_container {
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -250px;
}
```

Comment: The material-container wont have height or width, the contents inside will give to material-container the size, and i need that it always be horizontaly and verticaly center.

Comment: you can give min-height then

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `css-tables` technique to vertically center.

See this [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/v7q6h/)

More about the the different techniques in [this post](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/).

Comment: I go to read that interesting post, but the jsfiddle dont works i thing

Comment: Did you see the demo - the material-container class looks vertically centered to me.

Comment: I see now you delete the absolute and top margin, is center yes. But i have a header and footer siblings of the template container and with display: table all brokes.